# Apache redirect alias to a different domain

Tags: apache-2.2

I previous had both Web and Mail on the same server and for each of my vhosts/domains, I could visit `example.com/mail` or `foo.com/mail` which would display the Roundcube Webmail across all vhosts.

E.g `Alias /mail "/usr/share/apache2/roundcub/"`

Although now I have moved the Mail server onto a completely different server and now have a SSL for the main domain. `https://mail.example.com` which is now the new location of Roundcube for all vhosts/domains.

**Question**: is it possible to redirect all alias for "/mail" from the Web server to the new URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible, but you would have to use a [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead of an alias.

```
Redirect /mail https://mail.example.com/mail
```